# javax.faces.FacesException: javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:

Tags: richfaces, ajax4jsf, propertynotfoundexception

I'm getting the below error when I try to access my application(using JSF,RichFaces,a4j frameworks).

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /facelets/home.xhtml @448,82 rendered="#{contact.visible}": ELResolver cannot handle a null base Object with identifier 'contact'
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:672)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:680)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:678)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:680)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:678)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:680)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:678)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:680)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:678)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.invokeOnComponent(UIComponentBase.java:680)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.encodeChildren(AjaxViewRoot.java:543)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:883)
at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:578)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:99)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.renderView(FlowViewHandler.java:99)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:108)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:266)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:159)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:245)
```

Below is piece of 'home.xhtml' page

```
     <h:dataTable id="contactsTable"
 value="#{agentBean.personalDetails.contactList}"
      var="contact" border="0" width="90%">
     <h:column>
     <a4j:region id="ContactTypeRegion">
     <h:selectOneMenu id="contactType"
     value="#{contact.contactType}"
required="#{param['contactValidation'] != '0'}"
requiredMessage="#{user.ContactTypeRequired}">
<f:selectItems
value="#{contact.contactTypeList}" />
<a4j:support event="onchange"
focus="contactCode"
action="#{contact.enableContactNumber}"
reRender="ContactCodePanel,ContactNumPanel,EntensionPanel" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
</a4j:region>
<a4j:outputPanel id="ContactCodePanel">
<rich:spacer height="1" width="2" />
<h:inputText id="contactCode"
label="Contact Code"
value="#{contact.contactCountryCode}"
style="width:10%" class="txtBox"
required="#{param['contactValidation'] != '0'}"
requiredMessage="#{user.ContactCodeRequired}"
maxlength="3">
<f:validator
validatorId="NumericValidator" />
<f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="3" />
<rich:toolTip for="ContactCodePanel"
value="Area Code" direction="bottom-left"
styleClass="tooltip" />
<rich:ajaxValidator event="onblur" />
</h:inputText>
                                        <rich:spacer height="1" width="2" />
<h:outputText value="-" />
</a4j:outputPanel>
<rich:spacer height="1" width="2" />
```

Below is the point im getting the above error

```
<a4j:commandLink id="removeContact1"
value="#{contact.remove}"
rendered="#{contact.visible}"
reRender="contactsTable"
action="#{agentBean.personalDetails.removeContact}">
<a4j:actionparam name="contactValidation"
value="0" />
</a4j:commandLink>
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the **contactList** (referenced from **agentBean.personalDetails.contactList** in datatable) contains a null entry

Therefore the following expression can not be evaluated

```
rendered="#{contact.visible}"
```

Comment: I have set the default value also.but still im getting the error.Note: im using Tomcat6.x

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with default value. You just have to check that the list (contactList) that is returned from the managed bean through the personalDetails object, does not contain null entries. For example try the following
`<h:dataTable id="contactsTable"
 value="#{agentBean.personalDetails.contactList}"
      var="contact" border="0" width="90%">
     <h:column> #{contact}
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>`

and check if any of the columns is empty (meaning that the contact object is null)

Comment: Thanks enterlezi you are right the "object is empty".Could you tell me how to fix it."Im trying to add new values, so it would be always empty contactList for first time. (Note. I'm trying to run the code locally in my machine using Tomcat 6.x ..same code is working in webSphere server in Unix environment).

Comment: There is no problem with the contactList being empty. The problem is when the list contains null values. Check your managed bean named **agentBean** for a method `getPersonalDetails` and check the return class. That class should have a method `getContactList`. This method returns a list and you should ensure that the returned list does **NOT** contain any null value. Iterate the list and remove any nulls, for example use the following piece of code `list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));` before returning it

Comment: I tried the same way ,but no luck.. getting same error.. javax.faces.FacesException: javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /facelets/home.xhtml @260,85 rendered="#{contact.visible}": ELResolver cannot handle a null base Object with identifier 'contact'.                                               Should any other things needs to do?

Comment: Based on what you have written here, the problem is that the list contains a null value. So i am not sure if there is something else you can do. Try to debug the application and check what value is returned from `getContactList` when the page is rendered

Comment: Thanks enterlezi.. I removed that rendered condition and its worked.